# Recognition of a graph as a product of its quotients

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Is there an algorithm to determine whether a given simple graph $G$ is a product graph, typically, say a cartesian product graph of two smaller simple graphs $G_1, G_2$, such that the two simple graphs have the cartesian product of their vertex sets having the same cardinality of the graph $G$, that is, $V(G_1)\times V(G_2)=V(G)$?

Since every graph could be written as a cartesian product of some graphs(though some might be degenerate), I think it would be possible to determine whether a graph is the product (any graph product) of two simpler graphs in a nice way.

Comment: I recommend Chapter Five of Algebras, Lattices, Varieties Volume 1 authored by McKenzie, McNulty, and Taylor. Although much of the focus is on algebras having a direct product decomposition (and one can look at the congruences for information on this), some mention is made of relational structures such as graphs. Gerhard "Often Relates To Algebraic Structures" Paseman, 2019.10.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman could you give some other reference, as the link [here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/ALVin.pdf) has only contents of chapter five. Shall I look in some source dealing with unique factorisation of algebras?

Comment: Unique factorization might help, but also search for "direct decomposition" or "direct product decomposition". I recall the chapter talking about Jonsson and Tarski's joint and independent works. If you prefer just to work with graphs however, you might focus on works of graph theorists: some of them have been exposed to universal algebra.  Gerhard "Can't Recall Those Names Now" Paseman, 2019.10.22.

Comment: Try to do a bit on your own! Googling "recognising cartesian product of graphs" gives the wikipedia page as first hit, which contains the answer, and the second hit is the paper in Bullet51's answer...

Comment: @verret actually I never knew that there was a unique factorisation for connected graphs with respect to cartesian products. Didnt read the wikipedia page correctly! So does the set of connected graphs with cartesian product operation as multiplication and disjoint union as addition form a UFD?

Comment: @verret the cartesian product recognition may be well studied, but are there similar algorithms for other products? This is non-trivial,I hope

Comment: Have you tried looking for references? What have you found so far? These are all things you should do before asking a question, and then include as context, to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best algorithm is linear in the number of edges:see [Imrich, Wilfried; Peterin, Iztok (2007), "Recognizing Cartesian products in linear time", Discrete Mathematics 307 (3-5): 472–483](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X06005280).

An easy-to-understand algorithm can be found [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_decompositions/graph_products.html), which is basically keeping a set of edges that necessarily come from the same factor of the product graph. If all edges are necessarily from the same factor, the graph is not a nontrivial product. Otherwise there exists a decomposition.

Comment: thanks! but are there similar algorithms for other products?